# Add Tag while uploading an object to Amazon s3 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to upload CSV files to Amazon S3.

I'm able to add metadata using the below code snippet:

```
s3_obj.upload_file(file_to_be_uploaded, {"content_type": "application/octet-stream"}
```

How can I add suitable tags (key-value pairs) -- for example `exp: tag = { marked_to_delete: "true" }` --  while uploading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do that by passing `tagging: "marked_to_delete=true"` as an option.

Options are passed to an instance of `AWS::S3::Client`'s `put_object` method. The docs give a similar [example](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/9ea447b7e9e57e27bb7924aca40a5bf0c3265a94/gems/aws-sdk-s3/lib/aws-sdk-s3/client.rb#L5138):

```
resp = client.put_object({
  body: "filetoupload", 
  bucket: "examplebucket", 
  key: "exampleobject", 
  server_side_encryption: "AES256", 
  tagging: "key1=value1&key2=value2", 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response Jan. Tried above code snippet with tagging: "marked_to_delete=true" and got " unexpected value at params[:tagging] "

Comment: Tags getting created after upgrading aws sdk('aws-sdk', '~> 3') . Thanks!!