# How to allow a user to upload an image to S3 with tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, amazon-s3

I'm working on a project for school.  I have it set up so that users can upload images to the web app via a form, Active Record and AWS S3.  What I would like is for the user to be able to add a tag to the image so it can be organised by tags later.  I read about tags on the AWS docs but it seems to all be in the AWS CLI which the user won't be using.  Is there anyone that can simplify how I can do this in Rails?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047085/add-tag-while-uploading-an-object-to-amazon-s3-in-rails

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/9ea447b7e9e57e27bb7924aca40a5bf0c3265a94/gems/aws-sdk-s3/lib/aws-sdk-s3/client.rb#L5138

Comment: Just add a taggable column to the table storing the file records that you can use to help sort and search. This would be done on your db via a migration and not AWSS3